# Color-coded console output

Tags: c#, .net, console

I wrote this `Console.Write` function to use in my applications where I need to easily color-code output.

Example syntax would be:

```
Console.WriteLine("<f=red>this is in red");
Console.WriteLine("<b=gray><f=white>This is white on gray. <f=green>This is green on gray. <b=darkmagenta>This is green on dark magenta. <b=d>This is green on default.");
```

Which results in this...

[image: Console output of code]

I'm looking for a general review of the code.

```
//github.com/BenVlodgi/CommandHelper
public static class Console
{
    private static Regex _writeRegex = new Regex("<[fb]=\\w+>");

    public static void WriteLine(string value, int? cursorPosition = null, bool clearRestOfLine = false)
    {
        Write(value + Environment.NewLine, cursorPosition, clearRestOfLine);
    }

    public static void Write(string value, int? cursorPosition = null, bool clearRestOfLine = false)
    {
        if (cursorPosition.HasValue)
            System.Console.CursorLeft = cursorPosition.Value;

        ConsoleColor defaultForegroundColor = System.Console.ForegroundColor;
        ConsoleColor defaultBackgroundColor = System.Console.BackgroundColor;

        var segments = _writeRegex.Split(value);
        var colors = _writeRegex.Matches(value);

        for (int i = 0; i < segments.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                ConsoleColor consoleColor;
                // Now that we have the color tag, split it int two parts, 
                // the target(foreground/background) and the color.
                var splits = colors[i - 1].Value
                    .Trim(new char[] { '<', '>' })
                    .Split('=')
                    .Select(str => str.ToLower().Trim())
                    .ToArray();

                // if the color is set to d (default), then depending on our target,
                // set the color to be the default for that target.
                if (splits[1] == "d")
                    if (splits[0][0] == 'b')
                        consoleColor = defaultBackgroundColor;
                    else
                        consoleColor = defaultForegroundColor;
                else
                    // Grab the console color that matches the name passed. 
                    // If none match, then return default (black).
                    consoleColor = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor))
                        .Cast<ConsoleColor>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(en => en.ToString().ToLower() == splits[1]);

                // Set the now chosen color to the specified target.
                if (splits[0][0] == 'b')
                    System.Console.BackgroundColor = consoleColor;
                else
                    System.Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
            }

            // Only bother writing out, if we have something to write.
            if (segments[i].Length > 0)
                System.Console.Write(segments[i]);
        }

        System.Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForegroundColor;
        System.Console.BackgroundColor = defaultBackgroundColor;

        if (clearRestOfLine)
            ClearRestOfLine();
    }

    public static void ClearRestOfLine()
    {
        int winTop = System.Console.WindowTop;
        int left = System.Console.CursorLeft;
        System.Console.Write(new string(' ', System.Console.WindowWidth - left));
        System.Console.CursorLeft = left;
        System.Console.CursorTop--;
        System.Console.WindowTop = winTop;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be interested in this project https://github.com/DITLeonel/GetBootstrap

Comment: and basically all of this guy's questions http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29034/leonel?tab=questions

Comment: Didn't your mother ever tell you to use Curly Braces?

Comment: @RubberDuck Boot strap is neat, but I've written my own methods like those before, and they still have the problem being separate calls for each color desired. I wrote this so that I could inline the changing of colors.

Comment: Liking this effort/project, is it anywhere on GitHub or sorts?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe yes, but I haven't been maintaining it very well. It is here on [GitHub](http://github.com/BenVlodgi/CommandHelper).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments are inline.

> ```
> public static class Console
> ```

Where's your `using` directives? They're needed for the code to compile; you should post them.

It's a little bit unusual to give your class the same name as one in `System` but I see why you did it -- so you can just switch to using your new module with a `using`.

> ```
> {
>     private static Regex _writeRegex = new Regex("<[fb]=\\w+>");
> ```

Don't forget to make it `readonly`. The pattern for that `Regex` should be specified as a verbatim string literal so you don't have to double the backslashes (only you can prevent Leaning Toothpick Syndrome) -- `@"<[FB]\w+>"`. You don't save length but it's easier to understand.

I had initially thought that it might make sense to construct this `Regex` using `RegexOptions.Compiled`, but it turns out that has no benefit since it's only used in a `static` method, so it will automatically be cached. But if you ever use nonstatic methods, it's worth trying it and see if it gives a speed increase.

> ```
>     public static void WriteLine(string value, int? cursorPosition = null, bool clearRestOfLine = false)
>     {
>         Write(value + Environment.NewLine, cursorPosition, clearRestOfLine);
>     }
> ```

It's inefficient to use `+` here to append onto the `string`. Since .NET `System.String` is immutable, it has to build a whole new `string` and copy. It would be better to just call `Write` with the parameters as you got them, followed by `System.Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);`.

> ```
>     public static void Write(string value, int? cursorPosition = null, bool clearRestOfLine = false)
>     {
>         if (cursorPosition.HasValue)
>             System.Console.CursorLeft = cursorPosition.Value;
>
>         ConsoleColor defaultForegroundColor = System.Console.ForegroundColor;
>         ConsoleColor defaultBackgroundColor = System.Console.BackgroundColor;
>
>         var segments = _writeRegex.Split(value);
>         var colors = _writeRegex.Matches(value);
> ```

This seems a bit inefficient since you're doing the same matching twice. I strongly suspect that it would be better to skip the `.Split` call and use a `foreach` loop on the `Matches`.

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < segments.Length; i++)
>         {
>             if (i > 0)
> ```

As another reviewer suggested, this is suboptimal. If `i==0` is a special case, move it outside the loop so you don't need to test `i` each time through the loop. (The compiler will probably do this for you, so you won't gain any speed -- it's just for code legibility)

> ```
>             {
>                 ConsoleColor consoleColor;
>                 // Now that we have the color tag, split it int two parts, 
>                 // the target(foreground/background) and the color.
>                 var splits = colors[i - 1].Value
>                     .Trim(new char[] { '<', '>' })
>                     .Split('=')
>                     .Select(str => str.ToLower().Trim())
>                     .ToArray();
> ```

This is clever, but it really would be easier and clearer to just use capturing groups in your `Regex` so you can access the two parts directly from the `Match`.

> ```
>                 // if the color is set to d (default), then depending on our target,
>                 // set the color to be the default for that target.
>                 if (splits[1] == "d")
>                     if (splits[0][0] == 'b')
> ```

This code would be a lot clearer if you used meaningful variable names instead of `splits[1]` and `splits[0]`.

> ```
>                         consoleColor = defaultBackgroundColor;
>                     else
>                         consoleColor = defaultForegroundColor;
> ```

You like terseness -- how about the ternary operator here?

> ```
>                 else
>                     // Grab the console color that matches the name passed. 
>                     // If none match, then return default (black).
>                     consoleColor = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor))
>                         .Cast<ConsoleColor>()
>                         .FirstOrDefault(en => en.ToString().ToLower() == splits[1]);
> ```

Again, very clever, but I think it would be more efficient to just build a `Dictionary<string,ConsoleColor>` one time at the start, rather than searching the whole list each time. LINQ is extremely useful; that doesn't mean it's best used everywhere.

> ```
>                 // Set the now chosen color to the specified target.
>                 if (splits[0][0] == 'b')
>                     System.Console.BackgroundColor = consoleColor;
>                 else
>                     System.Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
>             }
>
>             // Only bother writing out, if we have something to write.
>             if (segments[i].Length > 0)
>                 System.Console.Write(segments[i]);
>         }
> ```

Like the other reviewer said, this `if` should be at the start so you don't bother unpacking the string at all.

> ```
>         System.Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForegroundColor;
>         System.Console.BackgroundColor = defaultBackgroundColor;
> ```

How about `System.Console.ResetColor()`? It would make these two variables unnecessary.

> ```
>         if (clearRestOfLine)
>             ClearRestOfLine();
>     }
>
>     public static void ClearRestOfLine()
>     {
>         int winTop = System.Console.WindowTop;
>         int left = System.Console.CursorLeft;
>         System.Console.Write(new string(' ', System.Console.WindowWidth - left));
>         System.Console.CursorLeft = left;
>         System.Console.CursorTop--;
>         System.Console.WindowTop = winTop;
>     }
> }
> ```

Does this do what you want after a `WriteLine`? It looks to me like it clears the next line not the current one.

Comment: Thanks @Snowbody, you brought up some very good points. `WriteLine` does not work as I intended, though it does, if I take your recommondation to use a separate `System.Console.WriteLine();` after 'Write`ing out the text.

Comment: I keep the currently set console colors as the defaults, because they may be different from the actual console defaults. On top of that, I need to be able to just set one at a time and not both.

Answer (score 5):

you should definitely be using Curly Braces here

> ```
>             // if the color is set to d (default), then depending on our target,
>             // set the color to be the default for that target.
>             if (splits[1] == "d")
>                 if (splits[0][0] == 'b')
>                     consoleColor = defaultBackgroundColor;
>                 else
>                     consoleColor = defaultForegroundColor;
>             else
>                 // Grab the console color that matches the name passed. 
>                 // If none match, then return default (black).
>                 consoleColor = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor))
>                     .Cast<ConsoleColor>()
>                     .FirstOrDefault(en => en.ToString().ToLower() == splits[1]);
> ```

You have comments and multilined, single line code inside of an else statement.  This calls for Curly Braces

and the if/else block inside of another if block, and no Curly Braces?!  this is begging for Curly Braces.

Comment: I abhor curly braces. But I expected nothing less.

Comment: Abhor them all you want, but there's no getting rid of them when you have more than one line. Which is a lot of code.

Comment: @MillieSmith and until I have more than one line of code, I will not add them

Comment: an if *and else* statement counts as more than one line of code inside of another if statement, even if it compiles the way you anticipate, it is still a bad habit to remove the curly braces from such a block of code.  but hey maybe you would like VB or Python much better than C# or Java...